# React-Native: How to open google play store from react native app?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to find a way how to open the google play store with my application when the user is pressing a button inside of the react-native application. Is there a way how to do this?

Comment: Check out `Linking` : http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use deeplinking to redirect your user from your app using this:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html

and the `Linking` API from react-native:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Answer (score 75):

If people are too lazy to read through the annoyingly SPA dev docs of android:

```js
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

In react-native land:

```js
Linking.openURL("market://details?id=<package_name>");
```

Example:

```js
Linking.openURL("market://details?id=googoo.android.btgps");
```

Edit:
Make sure to import `Linking` in order to use it

```js
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Linking } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: I got `"Could not open URL 'market://detail?id=': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://detail?id= flg=0x10000000 }"` error.

Comment: are you testing on a physical device or in the emulator?

Comment: I am getting can't find variable Linking

Comment: It's included in the RN APIs 

Gotta import it with the rest of your stuff:

`import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Linking } from 'react-native';`

Answer (score 6):

For future users, you could go on to read the docs from the accepted answer for more info. But if you want a faster result, here it is.

Using `Linking` from `react-native` as

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'

Linking.openURL("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>")
```

If you're using expo, then the below code is for you.

Install the `expo-linking` package via `expo install expo-linking`

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

Linking.openURL("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>")
```

**NOTE:** `<package_name>` is your app's package name defined in the manifest file or `app.json` if you're using expo

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :
Go to google play . search your app there and copy the url and put like below

```
import { Linking } from "react-native";
Linking.openURL("your app url her")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Expo Linking docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#custom-url-schemes) mentions.

> It's possible that the user doesn't have the Lyft app installed, in which case you may want to open the App / Play Store, or let them know that they need to install it first. We recommend using the library [react-native-app-link](https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link) for these cases.

It's got an MIT license so we're good to use it.

Let's see how that library does it!

https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link/blob/master/index.js

```
export const openInStore = async ({ appName, appStoreId, appStoreLocale = 'us', playStoreId }) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    Linking.openURL(`https://apps.apple.com/${appStoreLocale}/app/${appName}/id${appStoreId}`);
  } else {
    Linking.openURL(
      `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${playStoreId}`
    );
  }
};
```

So I modified it to:

```
export const openInStore = async (config: {
    appStoreConfig: {
        appName: string;
        appId: string;
        storeLocale: string;
    };
    playStoreConfig: {
        appId: string;
    };
}) => {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        await Linking.openURL(
            `https://apps.apple.com/${config.appStoreConfig.storeLocale}/app/${config.appStoreConfig.appName}/id${config.appStoreConfig.appId}`
        );
    } else if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        await Linking.openURL(
            `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${config.playStoreConfig.appId}`
        );
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
try {
    openInStore({
        playStoreConfig: {appId: "com.stevemoretz.test"},
        appStoreConfig: {
            appId: "com.stevemoretz.test",
            appName: "Test",
            storeLocale: "us",
        },
    });
} catch (e) {}
```

Should work but haven't been tested yet!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this package is a cool alternative.

Available for React Native, and Expo

https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check