# Better way to show force update app dialog box

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to show user a new version of application is available and it is mandatory for user to update. But when I am using the api provided by the google and app store it shows me the new version but when redirected to app store/play store there isn't any update button available. The only buttons available are uninstall and open and I have developed app using react native.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force users to update the app using react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579903/how-to-force-users-to-update-the-app-using-react-native)

Comment: Sorry for replying late, As I mentioned in question I am able to get the new version in api but when I redirect my app to the play store it doesn't show me UPDATE button. It shows me OPEN button