# Stop Alert from closing on onPress React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need an alert to force the user to update his app I'm alerting him to go to playstore when pressed he can then go back and continue, this is causing an error as I wanted it to stick until he updates it

Comment: please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579903/how-to-force-users-to-update-the-app-using-react-native), hopefully you will get helpful

Comment: @zein how are you checking whether the user is eligible for an update?

Comment: @AlokSingh do you have something for react native cli?

Comment: @GauravRoy it's not my current problem the problem is I want to override the default functionality of onPress event of Alert

Comment: please check it, hopefully it will helpful 

https://medium.com/@kinley.tshering/force-update-react-native-apps-a9c1f22c0701